# Tracking change in group by group with time lag

Tags: python, list, concatenation, pandas-groupby, lag

I have the following data frame which indicates for every individual to which employer they have been connected for which projects(and they can be connected to more than one employer for a project). The column year indicates the year(from which the digit indicates the order of the projects in a year (project 20122 is executed after project 20121))

```css
Employee_id = [7102825752, 7102825752, 7102825752, 7102825752, 7102825752, 7102825752, 7102825752, 7102825752, 7102825752, 7102825752]
Project_id = [28253288, 28648301, 28800042, 29113983, 29126250, 29364924, 29678870, 29691896, 29691235, 29691235]
Employer_id = [60031437, 60031437, 60033114, 115272656, 110625857, 60031437, 60031437, 60031437, 61273455, 85972742]
Year = [20121, 20122, 20131, 20141, 20151, 20152, 20161, 20161, 20162, 20162]

import pandas as pd
data = pd.DataFrame({"Employee_id":Employee_id,"Project_id":Project_id,"Employer_id":Employer_id,"Year":Year})
```

My aim is to track how the individuals changed between organisations, as can be displayed in the two columns on the right in the table below. I want to know which organisations they left compared to the previous year, and for which new organisations they started working (does not matter that they might also have worked for them in the past).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to my problem, maybe not nice, but it works

```
import pandas as pd
Employee_id = [7102825752, 7102825752, 7102825752, 7102825752, 7102825752, 
7102825752, 7102825752, 7102825752, 7102825752, 7102825752]
Project_id = [28253288, 28648301, 28800042, 29113983, 29126250, 29364924, 29678870, 29691896, 29691235, 29691235]
Employer_id = [60031437, 60031437, 60033114, 115272656, 110625857, 60031437, 60031437, 60031437, 61273455, 85972742]
Year = [20121, 20122, 20131, 20141, 20151, 20152, 20161, 20161, 20162, 20162]
data = pd.DataFrame({"employee":Employee_id,"project":Project_id,"employer":Employer_id,"year":Year})

employee_employer_change_df = pd.DataFrame({"employee":[0],"project":[0],"employer":[[0]]})
employee_employer_change_df['employer'] = employee_employer_change_df['employer'].astype(object)

for employee in set(data["employee"]):
    for project in data.loc[data['employee'] == employee]['project']:
        employer_list = data.loc[data.loc[data['employee'] == employee]['project']==project]["employer"].tolist()
        df=pd.DataFrame({"employee":[employee],"project":[project],"employer":[0]})
        df['employer'] = df['employer'].astype(object)
        df.at[0, "employer"] = employer_list
        employee_employer_change_df = employee_employer_change_df.append(df)
employee_employer_change_df = employee_employer_change_df.reset_index() 
employee_employer_change_df = employee_employer_change_df.drop(employee_employer_change_df.index[0])

employee_employer_change_df=employee_employer_change_df.drop_duplicates(["employee","project"],keep='first')
employee_employer_change_df['previous_employer'] = employee_employer_change_df.groupby(['employee'])['employer'].shift(1)


previous_employer=employee_employer_change_df['previous_employer'].tolist()
current_employer=employee_employer_change_df['employer'].tolist()

true=np.isnan(float('nan'))
new_employer_list = []
leaving_employer_list = []
for u in range(0,len(previous_employer)):
    nan_test=np.isnan(previous_employer[u])
    if nan_test is not true:
        new_employer_list.append(list(set(current_employer[u]) - set(previous_employer[u])))
        leaving_employer_list.append(list(set(previous_employer[u]) - set(current_employer[u])))
    else:
        new_employer_list.append(["first year"])
        leaving_employer_list.append(["first year"])

employee_employer_change_df['new_affiliation'] = new_employer_list     
employee_employer_change_df['leaving_affiliation'] = leaving_employer_list
```